# How to build NON-ecommerce websites on BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

How to build a non-ecommerce site on BigCommerce?
Want to use the CMS of BigCommerce but client will not be selling products.
For marketing purposes only doesn't need an ecart or product linting.
Not finding non-ecommerce thems there - can I use webdiv in dreamweaver and build my own design or use a template?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Just do not build out a product catalog. Use the "web pages" portion of the dashboard only to create content pages. You will not find non-ecommerce themes but that is not to say that you have to use the category, product, and checkout pages. 
As far as the template, you can create your own from scratch or customize an existing template.